# org-mode: limit export to selected headlines, i.e. opt-in for export

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

There's a command/option that I can put in my orgmode file that causes only headlines that are explicitly tagged with `:export:` get exported.  What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that

```
#+SELECT_TAGS: export
```

should do what you have in mind. Conversely if you want to exclude certain tags from being exported, you can use

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
```

For lots of other options to be applied during the export you can take a look at the org-mode manual at http://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-settings

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I messed up on the syntax -- I had put `INCLUDE_TAGS: export` in my `#+OPTIONS` line.